# Eclipse 2002 4 cylinders won't start

Tags: mitsubishi, eclipse

I was unable to start the car, I tested the battery and replaced the starter with a new one and the car is still not starting, I'm including the link to the video of how it sounds: https://youtu.be/G2wpPhR-rRs

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The video sounds like I'm only hearing the starter spin and not the engine? I'm only hearing a whirring sound ... is that what I'm supposed to be hearing?

Comment: Paulsre2, yes sir this is what I hear when I try to start the car, thanks

Comment: Timing Belt/chain is broken or stripped.

Comment: Thanks Moab, I will check the timing belt and let you know

Comment: Can you see any pulleys turning on the engine while someone else tries to start it?  Obviously keep your fingers away from the engine while you do this.

Comment: Hi guys, I checked the timing belt and looks fine and I also checked the pulleys and they are not turning

Comment: Just a quick update, I changed the camshaft position sensor but it didn't help and I'm going to change the crankshaft position sensor soon and post what happens.

Comment: So the starter turns, but the pulleys on the engine are not.  It is possible that the teeth on the starter pinion or the flywheel ring-gear are damaged.  There is no point in changing any sensors if the engine is not turning over.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that the starter doesn't engage to the flywheel. There is a mechanism that engages and disengages the starter to the flywheel and in rare cases can fail or stuck.

Still, you should be able to push start the car, if it doesn't start like this, then might be something more serious, but I'm sure you would know more about it.

However, I would first make sure that no fuse or relay is blown by following the wiring diagram in order to spot all the related circuits.

Before you replace any parts you could check if the starter engagement mechanism draws any current. If it does try tapping on the starter motor with a small mallet just to shake it a bit in the hope that it will unstuck it.

In case that the engagement mechanism doesn't draw any current, try to find on the electrical diagram the next place to check in case you missed anything or if any wire is lose.

Finally if all wiring is fine, then most likely you need to replace the starter.

Comment: I checked the starter with a battery and it was working fine, I guess I will have to the fuses/relays and the wiring for the starter

Comment: Read Alimba's answer again. Whether the starter runs on the bench is not determinative as to whether the starter pinion is engaging the flywheel teeth.

Comment: Based on your video, id pull the starter and inspect the teeth on both the flywheel side and starter side. It's definitely spinning but it isn't engaging with anything. Just out of curiosity was this the same problem before the starter was replaced?